# Center button in footerView

Tags: swift, uibutton

I want my button to be in the center of my footerView. I tried several methods but failed every time:

1.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#F9FAFB")
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:(footerView.frame.size.width - 30) / 2, y:(footerView.frame.size.height - 30) / 2, width: 30, height: 30))            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "gen-cog"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(footerButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        footerView.addSubview(button)
    }
```

2. Used auto layout, this centers my button but breaks width and height of it, which I set to 30 above.

   ```
   let centerYCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button,
                      attribute: .centerY,
                                       relatedBy: .equal,
                                       toItem: footerView,
                                       attribute: .centerY,
                                       multiplier: 1.0,
                                       constant: 0.0);
   footerView.addConstraint(centerYCon)

   let centerXCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button,
                                           attribute: .centerX,
                                           relatedBy: .equal,
                                           toItem: footerView,
                                           attribute: .centerX,
                                           multiplier: 1.0,
                                           constant: 0.0);
   footerView.addConstraint(centerXCon)
   footerView.addSubview(button)
   ```

3.

```
button.center = footerView.center
```

Comment: It's will work: `button.center = footerView.center`. You should call this inside `viewForFooterInSection`

Comment: it is not working, when I use this button centre will be at x:0 , y:0 of footerView

Comment: You have called this: `let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)`. It's actually nothing. You should give the right size and then you can detect the center itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  footerView.addSubview(button)
```

**Now Add two more additional Constraints.**

```
  let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
  let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
  button.addConstraints([widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
```